# How to display units of measurement as words

Tags: data, semantics, product-details

Due to some technical oddities, I'm unable to display **5'9"**.

My first thought was to show **5 foot 9 inches** but this feels far too long and requires a lot more reading then I'd like.

Would the user accept the use of **5ft 9in** for example? My only concern was the **in** part as I'm unsure how commonly this is used.

For context this is going into a product description on a fashion site.

Comment: I think this is better suited for [english.se]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think '5ft 9in' is fine. I think its a perfectly accepted abefviation of feet/inches.

The other way would be to use CM if you don't already do so, this metric tends to be more common on fashion sites that I've worked on and seen before.

Using both is something Ive seen too, Zara and Asos are good examples of this. This would be something to consider.

Comment: I am using cm as well, I'm based in the UK so I have to cover all angles since people from different generations prefer different units (just to make this more difficult).

Comment: Thats great, thought i'd mention it just in case.